# Draw a diagonal arrow across an expression in a formula to show that it vanishes

Tags: arrows, text-decorations, cancel, strikeout

I would like to find a way to cross out a term in a mathematical expression with a diagonal arrow pointing from lower left to upper right and with a little "zero" next to the pointy end of the arrow.

Answer (score 89):

You can use the [`cancel` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/cancel/cancel.pdf) (adding `\usepackage{cancel}` in the preamble of the document) that introduces the commands:

- `\cancel`: draws a diagonal line (slash) through its argument.
- `\bcancel`: uses the negative slope (a backslash).
- `\xcancel`: draws an X (actually `\cancel` plus `\bcancel`).
- `\cancelto{〈value〉}{〈expression〉}`: draws a diagonal arrow through the `〈expression〉`,
  pointing to the `〈value〉`.

For example, to get an arrow ending in a zero over parameter `$\phi$`, you would use `$\cancelto{0}{\phi}$`.

Comment: this doesn't work in a begin{equation} enviroment. 
Any solutions?

Comment: a work around is changing to 
\ [ .. \ ]
 but it looses the numbering