# Cross and almost equal to zero (negligible)

Tags: math-mode

How can i achieve the following mathematical construct with LaTeX?

[image]

Comment: Welcome, have you at least tried a little bit and can share that bit with us?

Comment: Sorry if my question is somehow elementary, I'm an absoloutely beginner with latex, I looked for it for a while and thought to asked it here

Comment: Exactly the same way as in [Cross out with arrow as in "goes to zero"](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/31325), just write `\simeq 0` instead of `0`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `cancel` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cancel}
\begin{document}
$\cancelto{\simeq 0}{A}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: One should not use `\simeq` for ‘almost equal to’. `\approx` is more  appropriate, in my opinion.

Comment: @Bernard I partially agree, that `\approx` makes more sense than `\simeq` for "approximately", but here either `A` goes to zero, then one denotes it by `\cancelto{0}{A}` or `A \to 0`, or `A` does not go to zero and one mustn't cancel it.