# multiple colors to cancelto

Tags: math-mode, color, cancel

Is it possible to assign multiple colors to the command "cancelto" of the package cancel? 
This answer [change color cancelto](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31323/cross-out-with-arrow-as-in-goes-to-zero/31370#31370) is almost there, but it changed the color for all the environments, at least it's my guess.

I was imagining something customizable, for example:

```
\renewcommand{\CancelColor}{\color{color of choice}} %%%%%%color as an input%%%%%%%

\cancelto[color of choice number 1]{0}{x}
\cancelto[color of choice number 2]{0}{x^2}
```

Regards,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This uses a different command with an optional argument that is meant for colour specification. If the argument isn't used the usual `\CancelColor` is applied.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\let\cancelorigcolor\CancelColor% Just for conveniency...

\newcommand{\CancelTo}[3][]{%
  \ifblank{#1}{}{%
    \renewcommand{\CancelColor}{#1}%
  }
  \cancelto{#2}{#3}% 
}

\begin{document}


$\cancelto{0}{x}$ versus $\CancelTo[\color{red}]{0}{x}$

Now again

$\CancelTo{0}{x}$ versus $\CancelTo[\color{blue}]{0}{x^2}$

and again

$\CancelTo[\color{brown}]{0}{x^3}$ versus $\CancelTo[\color{green}]{0}{x^2}$

and again and again 

$\CancelTo{0}{x^3}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\renewcommand{\CancelColor}{foocolor}` within an `equation` or `align` etc environment would of course not change the `\CancelColor` outside of that environment due to grouping

Comment: Perfect, great solution!Thx!