cancel arrows are drawn behind text and the arrow does not shorten the path
I was reading this answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/326370/319072 to change the colour of my cancel, when I noticed:

The cancel arrow is drawn behind the text it is canceling
the arrow tip does not shorten the path it is drawn on.

Is there a way to overcome this?

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\let\cancelorigcolor\CancelColor

\newcommand{\CancelTo}[3][]{%
  \ifblank{#1}{}{%
    \renewcommand{\CancelColor}{#1}%
  }
  \cancelto{#2}{#3}% 
}
\begin{document}
\[\CancelTo[\color{red}]{0}{abcdef}\]
\end{document}


EDIT2 with tikz without tikzmark
I added the overlay option and set 0 as the default value for parameter 2 of the command (#2)
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\tikzset{
    Arrow/.style = {
        -Latex[],
        red,
        % shorten >=-2pt, 
        % shorten <=-2pt,
        },
    N/.style = {
        %   draw,
        overlay,%<-- added
        anchor    =south west,
        inner sep =1pt,
        outer sep =0pt
        }
    }


    \NewDocumentCommand{\CancelToiii}{ m O{0} }
    {
        \tikz[baseline=(X.base),inner sep=0pt] 
            {
                \node (X) {$#1$};
                \draw[Arrow] (X.south west) -- (X.north east)node[N]{$#2$};
            }
    }
    \begin{document}
        \[A\CancelToiii{abcdef}B\]

        \[A\CancelToiii{ijk}[2x+3]B\]
\end{document}


With tikzmark
EDIT: Not to repeat specify a new letter for every \tikzmarknode I use a counter \newcounter{marque}
Code
\documentclass{article}
%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/726820/cancel-arrows-are-drawn-behind-text-and-the-arrow-does-not-shorten-the-path
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,tikzmark}
\tikzset{
  Arrow/.style = {
    -Latex[],
    red,
    % shorten >=-2pt, 
    % shorten <=-2pt,
    },
  N/.style = {
    %draw,
    anchor    =south west,
    inner sep =1pt
    }
}
\newcounter{marque}
\NewDocumentCommand{\Marque}{ m }
  {%
    \stepcounter{marque}
    \tikzmarknode{\themarque}{#1}
  }

\NewDocumentCommand{\CancelToii}{ m m }
  {
    \draw[Arrow] (#1.south west) -- (#1.north east)node[N]{$#2$};  
  }
\begin{document}


\[\Marque{abcdef}\]

\[hijk\]

\[\Marque{lmnop}\]


\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
  \foreach \n/\t in {1/0,2/2x+3}
      {\CancelToii{\n}{\t}}  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Old version
\documentclass{article}
%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/726820/cancel-arrows-are-drawn-behind-text-and-the-arrow-does-not-shorten-the-path
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,tikzmark}
\tikzset{
  Arrow/.style = {
    -Latex[],
    red,
    % shorten >=-2pt, 
    % shorten <=-2pt,
    },
  N/.style = {
    %draw,
    anchor    =south west,
    inner sep =1pt
    }
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\CancelToii}{ m m }
  {
    \draw[Arrow] (#1.south west) -- (#1.north east)node[N]{#2};  
  }
\begin{document}


\[\tikzmarknode{a}{abcdef}\]

\[hijk\]

\[\tikzmarknode{b}{lmnop}\]


\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
  \CancelToii{a}{0}
  \CancelToii{b}{2x+3}  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Thank you, this was educational to read. I haven't tinkered with it yet, so pardon if this is a bad question. I'm just curious, is it necessary to specify a new letter for every \tikzmarknode, or can it be put into a command which can be re-used? I may delete this comment after trying, if I figure it out. Thanks again!

I tried to answer your question. I edited the answer. There are surely other solutions. You can uncheck accept answer to encourage other users to submit their ideas.

I really like your answer, and am inclined to view it as correct. That being said, I will respect your idea to uncheck it, to allow other contributions. What would be a reasonable timeframe to leave the question open?

Since the answer doesn't use cancel, I think a delay of at least 2-3 days after an edit seems reasonable. Glad you like the answer.

New simpler version (edit2)
