# How to write crossed-out math in LaTeX?

Tags: math-mode, text-decorations, cancel, strikeout

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Draw a diagonal arrow across an expression in a formula to show that it vanishes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11897/draw-a-diagonal-arrow-across-an-expression-in-a-formula-to-show-that-it-vanishes)

As you might know from my other questions, I am still a newbie at LaTeX, so please don't expect me to know anything.

How would I write crossed-out math in LaTeX, which is similar to <del>this</del>, but the line is oblique.

Is that possible?

Comment: Have a look at the `cancel` package.

Comment: @Mico Could you provide further details?

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11897, or the [package documentation](http://texdoc.net/pkg/cancel).

Answer (score 164, accepted):

The comments above should have solved the problem. But I thought a minimal example will go a long way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[makeroom]{cancel}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\verb|\cancel{5y}|:
\[ x+\cancel{5y}=0\]
\verb|\bcancel{5y}|:
\[ x+\bcancel{5y}=0\]
\verb|\xcancel{5y}|:
\[ x+\xcancel{5y}=0\]
\verb|\cancelto{\infty}{5y}|:
\[ x+\cancelto{\infty}{5y}=0\]

The first three commands work in text mode also i.e., \cancel{5y}, \bcancel{5y} and 
\xcancel{5y} works but \verb|\cancelto{\infty}{5y}| is not. 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: For some reason, in some cases `\cancel` and variants have to be inside curly brackets, for example this works: `$x^{\cancel{5y}}$ while this fails `$x^\cancel{5y}$`. The error is `Missing { inserted. ... \mathchoice`.

Comment: @alfC When you write super/subscript, it is always better to use braces.