# Cancel maths expression with a down arrow

Tags: math-mode, cancel, strikeout

The following  [solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/75530/11162) to the [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75525/how-to-write-crossed-out-math-in-latex/75530#75530) where soome maths text is to be cancelled out makes use of the `cancel` package. There the macro `\cancelto` produces an arrow from bottom left to top right. It also gives a macro called `\bcancel` which gives a strike out from top left to bottom right.

Is it possible to have a macro that combines these two together, something of the form `\bcancelto`: an arrow from top-left to bottom-right.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[makeroom]{cancel}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\verb|\cancel{5y}|:
\[ x+\cancel{5y}=0\]
\verb|\bcancel{5y}|:
\[ x+\bcancel{5y}=0\]
\verb|\xcancel{5y}|:
\[ x+\xcancel{5y}=0\]
\verb|\cancelto{\infty}{5y}|:
\[ x+\cancelto{\infty}{5y}=0\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is `\xcancel{}` what you want?

Comment: @Sigur No. What I need is something like an arrow from top left to bottom right.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I introduce `\bcancelto{label}{term}` by modifying one of the packages routines.  EDITED to support labels on `\bcancelto`.

The modification to `\canto@vector` to produce `\cantox@vector` amounted to three things:

1) adding a `-` before `#4` in the `\vector` call;

2) Changing the `^` superscript to a `_` subscript before the `\raise`; and

3) adding a `-` sign before `#2` following the `\raise`.

Then I had to define `\bcancelto` to make this macro substitution and call on `\cancelto` with the substitution in place.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[makeroom]{cancel}
\makeatletter
% #1, #2 offset of label   #6 extra width to clear arrowhead
% #3, #4 vector direction  #7 superscript label style
% #5 vector width          #8 superscript label
\def\cantox@vector#1#2#3#4#5#6#7#8{%
  \dimen@.5\p@
  \setbox\z@\vbox{\boxmaxdepth.5\p@
   \hbox{\kern-1.2\p@\kern#1\dimen@$#7{#8}\m@th$}}%
  \ifx\canto@fil\hidewidth  \wd\z@\z@ \else \kern-#6\unitlength \fi
  \ooalign{%
    \canto@fil$\m@th \CancelColor
    \vcenter{\hbox{\dimen@#6\unitlength \kern\dimen@
      \multiply\dimen@#4\divide\dimen@#3 \vrule\@depth\dimen@\@width\z@
      \vector(#3,-#4){#5}%
    }}_{\raise-#2\dimen@\copy\z@\kern-\scriptspace}$%
    \canto@fil \cr
    \hfil \box\@tempboxa \kern\wd\z@ \hfil \cr}}
\def\bcancelto#1#2{\let\canto@vector\cantox@vector\cancelto{#1}{#2}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\noindent
\verb|\cancel{5y}|:
\[ x+\cancel{5y}=0\]
\verb|\bcancel{5y}|:
\[ x+\bcancel{5y}=0\]
\verb|\xcancel{5y}|:
\[ x+\xcancel{5y}=0\]
\verb|\cancelto{\infty}{5y}|:
\[ x+\cancelto{\infty}{5y}=0\]
\noindent NEW! \verb|\bcancelto{\infty}{5y}|:
\[ x+\bcancelto{\infty}{5y}=0\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Here is a TikZ solution.

```
\documentclass[varwidth,border=50]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{
main node/.style={inner sep=0,outer sep=0},
label node/.style={inner sep=0,outer ysep=.2em,outer xsep=.4em,font=\scriptsize,overlay},
strike out/.style={shorten <=-.2em,shorten >=-.5em,overlay}
}
\newcommand{\cancelto}[3][]{\tikz[baseline=(N.base)]{
  \node[main node](N){$#2$};
  \node[label node,#1, anchor=south west] at (N.north east){$#3$};
  \draw[strike out,-latex,#1]  (N.south west) -- (N.north east);
}}
\newcommand{\bcancelto}[3][]{\tikz[baseline=(N.base)]{
  \node[main node](N){$#2$};
  \node[label node,#1, anchor=north west] at (N.south east){$#3$};
  \draw[strike out,-latex,#1]  (N.north west) -- (N.south east);
}}

\begin{document}
  \cancelto[orange]{test}{Oooo!}
    and math
  $\sqrt{\cancelto[red]{x}{\infty}}$

  \bcancelto[orange]{test}{Oooo!}
    and math
  $\sqrt{\bcancelto[red]{x}{\infty}}$
\end{document}
```

[image]