# Abnormally stretched arrow inside environment

Tags: tikz-arrows

I am trying to use  the solution offered by *Kpym* in [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/218372/cancel-maths-expression-with-a-down-arrow/218430) topic.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tasks} 

\pagestyle{empty}


\tikzstyle{fancytitle3}=[draw=black, fill=white, text=black, rounded corners = 3pt, inner sep = 3]
\NewEnviron{sol}{%
 \begin{center}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[rectangle, rounded corners = 7pt, inner sep = 10 ,minimum width=0.9\textwidth,
     text opacity=1,
    draw=orange, ultra thick, draw opacity=1,
    fill=white, fill opacity=1] (box)
    {%
        \begin{minipage}{.95\textwidth}
         \begin{small}\textsl{\BODY}\end{small}
        \end{minipage}
    };
     \node[fancytitle3, right=5pt] at (box.north west) {\textsl{\textbf{\begin{small}Solution \end{small}} }};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
}
\tikzset{
main node/.style={inner sep=0,outer sep=0},
label node/.style={inner sep=0,outer ysep=.2em,outer xsep=.4em,font=\scriptsize,overlay},
strike out/.style={shorten <=-.2em,shorten >=-.5em,overlay}
}
\newcommand{\cancelto}[3][]{\tikz[baseline=(N.base)]{
  \node[main node](N){$#2$};
  \node[label node,#1, anchor=south west] at (N.north east){$#3$};
  \draw[strike out,-latex,#1]  (N.south west) -- (N.north east);
}}
\newcommand{\bcancelto}[3][]{\tikz[baseline=(N.base)]{
  \node[main node](N){$#2$};
  \node[label node,#1, anchor=north west] at (N.south east){$#3$};
  \draw[strike out,-latex,#1]  (N.north west) -- (N.south east);
}}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    \text{This is good:}\qquad \cancelto[red]{2x-1}{1}
\end{align*}
\begin{sol}
\begin{align*}
    \text{We don't want this:}\qquad \cancelto[red]{2x-1}{1}
\end{align*}
\end{sol}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see, when I use the `\cancelto` inside the solution environment, something is telling tex to stretch the arrow and I'm not sure what is causing it.

I am aware of the `cancel` package, which doesn't exhibit this problem. At this stage, I am more interested in whether current situation can be mended.

Comment: You have nested `tikzpicture` environments, which is a no-no... The `sol` environemnt uses puts its content within a `tikzpicture` and then the `\cancelto` invokes another `tikzpicture` (via the `\tikz`).

Comment: @PeterGrill a no-no it is, then. Perhaps, I'd have more luck modifying the existing cancel commands.

Comment: Not necessarily... wait...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to work around this issue is to use a box and typeset the contents into that:

[image]

### References:

- Use `tikzset` instead of `\tikzstyle`: [Should \tikzset or \tikzstyle be used to define TikZ styles?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/52372/4301)
- I also replaced the `center` environment with `\centering` as that results in less vertical spacing.

### Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tasks} 

\pagestyle{empty}


\tikzset{fancytitle3/.style={draw=black, fill=white, text=black, rounded corners = 3pt, inner sep = 3}}

\newsavebox{\MyBox}
\NewEnviron{sol}{%
  \savebox{\MyBox}{%
      \begin{minipage}{.95\textwidth}
        \begin{small}\textsl{\BODY}\end{small}
       \end{minipage}%
  }%
 \centering
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[rectangle, rounded corners = 7pt, inner sep = 10 ,minimum width=0.9\textwidth,
     text opacity=1,
    draw=orange, ultra thick, draw opacity=1,
    fill=white, fill opacity=1] (box)
    {%
        \usebox{\MyBox}%
    };
     \node[fancytitle3, right=5pt] at (box.north west) {\textsl{\textbf{\begin{small}Solution \end{small}} }};
\end{tikzpicture}%
}
\tikzset{
main node/.style={inner sep=0,outer sep=0},
label node/.style={inner sep=0,outer ysep=.2em,outer xsep=.4em,font=\scriptsize,overlay},
strike out/.style={shorten <=-.2em,shorten >=-.5em,overlay}
}
\newcommand{\cancelto}[3][]{%
\begingroup
    \tikz[baseline=(N.base)]{
        \node[main node](N){$#2$};
        \node[label node,#1, anchor=south west] at (N.north east){$#3$};
        \draw[strike out,-latex,#1]  (N.south west) -- (N.north east);
    }%
\endgroup
}
\newcommand{\bcancelto}[3][]{%
  \tikz[baseline=(N.base)]{
  \node[main node](N){$#2$};
  \node[label node,#1, anchor=north west] at (N.south east){$#3$};
  \draw[strike out,-latex,#1]  (N.north west) -- (N.south east);
}}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    \text{This is good:}\qquad \cancelto[red]{2x-1}{1}
\end{align*}
\begin{sol}
\begin{align*}
    \text{This is now also good:}\qquad \cancelto[red]{2x-1}{1}
\end{align*}
\end{sol}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Interesting, do you use a box to make it look like it's not nesting tikzpictures?

Comment: @AlvinLepik: Yeah, when the box is being typeset it is _not_ in a `tikzpicture` (Note that the box is typeset _before_ `\begin{tikzpicture}`) . Then in the `tikzpicture` I just use the already typset contents of the box.

Answer (score 6):

No need to reinvent the wheel, the `tcolorbox` package allows you to create a box that does what you want.

Output:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tasks} 

\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

% title style "solution" 
\tcbset{titleresume/.style={boxed title style={colframe=black,colbacktitle=white,arc=3pt,boxrule=.6pt}}}

% box creating the box "solution"
\newtcolorbox{solution}{
titleresume,arc=7pt,width=0.95\textwidth,
colframe=orange,colbacktitle=white,coltitle=black,colback=white,fonttitle=\sl\bfseries\large,
center,boxrule=1.6pt,%boxsep=10pt,
enhanced,nobeforeafter,
attach boxed title to top left={yshift=-3mm,xshift=5pt},
title={Solution}}


\tikzset{
main node/.style={inner sep=0,outer sep=0},
label node/.style={inner sep=0,outer ysep=.2em,outer xsep=.4em,font=\scriptsize,overlay},
strike out/.style={shorten <=-.2em,shorten >=-.5em,overlay}
}
\newcommand{\cancelto}[3][]{\tikz[baseline=(N.base)]{
  \node[main node](N){$#2$};
  \node[label node,#1, anchor=south west] at (N.north east){$#3$};
  \draw[strike out,-latex,#1]  (N.south west) -- (N.north east);
}}
\newcommand{\bcancelto}[3][]{\tikz[baseline=(N.base)]{
  \node[main node](N){$#2$};
  \node[label node,#1, anchor=north west] at (N.south east){$#3$};
  \draw[strike out,-latex,#1]  (N.north west) -- (N.south east);
}}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    \text{This is good:}\qquad \cancelto[red]{2x-1}{1}
\end{align*}

\begin{solution}
\begin{align*}
    \text{This is good too:}\qquad \cancelto[red]{2x-1}{1}
\end{align*}
\end{solution}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Oh, that is a very neat alternative!