# Making TikZ cancel "overlay aware" in Beamer

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

How to make TikZ cancel  "overlay aware" in Beamer?

Code taken from  [Cancel maths expression with a down arrow](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/218372/cancel-maths-expression-with-a-down-arrow?noredirect=1&lq=1)

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{
main node/.style={inner sep=0,outer sep=0},
label node/.style={inner sep=0,outer ysep=.2em,outer xsep=.4em,font=\scriptsize,overlay},
strike out/.style={shorten <=-.2em,shorten >=-.5em,overlay},
strikee out/.style={shorten <=-.2em,shorten >=-.2em,overlay}
}
%
\newcommand{\cancel}[2][]{\tikz[baseline=(N.base)]{
  \node[main node](N){$#2$};
  \draw[strikee out,#1]  (N.south west) -- (N.north east);
}}
%
\begin{document}
%
\begin{frame}
\begin{align*}
a &= \frac{b}{c}\\
&= \frac{b}{b \cdot d}\\
\end{align*}
\end{frame}
%
%
\begin{frame}
\begin{align*}
a &= \frac{b}{c}\\
&= \frac{\cancel[red]{b}}{\cancel[red]{b} \cdot d}\\
\end{align*}
\end{frame}
%
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I take that you want to cancel only on certain frames. If so, you might be looking for the `overlay-beamer-styles` library. You only need to add `visible on=<...>` for the cancel line being visible on the frames `...`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles}
\tikzset{
main node/.style={inner sep=0,outer sep=0},
label node/.style={inner sep=0,outer ysep=.2em,outer xsep=.4em,font=\scriptsize,overlay},
strike out/.style={shorten <=-.2em,shorten >=-.5em,overlay},
strikee out/.style={shorten <=-.2em,shorten >=-.2em,overlay}
}
%
\newcommand{\Cancel}[2][]{\tikz[baseline=(N.base)]{
  \node[main node](N){$#2$};
  \draw[strikee out,#1]  (N.south west) -- (N.north east);
}}
%
\begin{document}
%
%
\begin{frame}
\begin{align*}
a &= \frac{b}{c}\\
&= \frac{\Cancel[red,visible on=<2>]{b}}{\Cancel[red,visible on=<2>]{b} \cdot d}\\
\end{align*}
\end{frame}
%
\end{document}
```

[image]