# Cancel (cross out) normal text in non-math mode

Tags: cancel

I want to cross out a letter. I found [Draw a diagonal arrow across an expression in a formula to show that it vanishes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11897/draw-a-diagonal-arrow-across-an-expression-in-a-formula-to-show-that-it-vanishes) but this works in mathmode only and mathmode changes the font. Is there a way to do the same without going to math mode? I need this for a slide where I want to have a really big font and wnat to `remove' the first letter of a word.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{cancel}

\begin{document}

$\xcancel{T}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Donald Arseneau said in the documentation that "Drawing slashes through math to indicate “cancellation” is poor design." So what is the rich design? :-)

Answer (score 10):

Why should one worry when there is `tikz`? ;)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\tcancel}[2][thick]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[inner sep=1pt] (a){#2};
\draw[#1] (a.south west) -- (a.north east);
\draw[#1] (a.north west) -- (a.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}%
}
\begin{document}
\tcancel{T} 

\tcancel[red,line width=1pt]{T}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Thanks to Claudio Fiandrino`s idea that this can be improved further

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}
\newcommand{\tcancel}[2][black]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw=#1,cross out,inner sep=1pt] (a){#2};
\end{tikzpicture}%
}
\begin{document}
\tcancel{T}

\tcancel[red,thick]{T}
\end{document}
```

The baseline may be corrected by `[baseline={(a.base)}]`as in

```
\newcommand{\tcancel}[2][black]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={(a.base)}]
\node[draw=#1,cross out,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt] (a){#2};
\end{tikzpicture}%
}
```

Adjust `inner` and `outer sep`s as you wish.

[image]

Comment: You can even improve it just using one node and the shape `cross out` (it requires `shapes.misc` library).

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino Thanks for the idea. I have updated the answer.

Comment: @Mico To use it with other text, some polishing is needed. I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 8):

You could achieve your objective by creating a macro named, say, `\tcancel` (short for text-mode cancel...) as a text-mode wrapper around `\xcancel`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for \ensuremath and \text macros
\newcommand{\tcancel}[1]{\ensuremath{\xcancel{\text{#1}}}}
\begin{document}
$\xcancel{T}$ (letter is in math mode)

\tcancel{T} (letter is in text mode)
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

`\mbox{}` can be used to switch back to text mode from math:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{cancel}

\begin{document}

$\xcancel{\mbox{T}}$

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]