# How can I place a "slash" -- / -- through a letter in this way?

Tags: math-mode, symbols, physics

I am writing a paper expanding on the results of a previous paper, and I want to preserve their terminology, at one point they use this symbol:

[image]

I have no idea how they made it nor how to reproduce it, when I try to copy it I get "p/" so I imagine that maybe they superimposed both symbols.

Thanks.

Comment: I forgot to mention, I know how to add the T and the ||, the bar in the middle is what is giving me trouble

Comment: Maybe `\cancel{p}` from the `cancel` package suits your needs (see: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11897/134144)?

Comment: Someone edited the title and added the picture, which is great, the title is better and the picture helped, but... who takes the time to do these things?

Comment: potential duplicate: [How to negate a specific symbol?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/140996)

Answer (score 7):

This is another solution:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{cancel}

\begin{document}
    $\cancel{p}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: It appears that if I use that, and type `\cancel{p}` in between `\begin{align*} ... \end{align*}`, then I get an undefined control sequence?

Comment: Never mind; that was my own separate error lol

Answer (score 3):

For the `p` with the slash symbol, I'd write

```
${p\mkern-7.5mu/}$
```

For the full, three-part symbol, I'd write

```
${p\mkern-7.5mu/}\mkern-1.8mu\raisebox{-0.35ex}{\scriptsize T}^{\parallel}$
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=1pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
${p\mkern-7.5mu/}\mkern-1.8mu\raisebox{-0.35ex}{\scriptsize T}^{\parallel}$
\end{document}
```